# Ошибка React ( Unexpected token (4:26) )

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Доброго времени суток, только недавно начал учить React, поэтому прошу не судить меня строго. Пытаюсь написать компонент поиска, но всё время выдаёт ошибку. Не могу понять почему и что я не так делаю. Весь код здесь 
https://github.com/VadoSevich/React-MyPractice-/blob/master/React%234/note.js. Но а это собственно место, где оно находит ошибку (строка с handleSearch). Заранее спасибо.

```
var Search = React.createClass({
    render: function() {

  handleSearch: function(event) {
      var searchQuery = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
      var displayedContacts = notes.filter(function(el) {
          var searchValue = el.name.toLowerCase();
          return searchValue.indexOf(searchQuery) !== -1;
      });
  },

  return (
      <input type="text" className="search" onChange={this.handleSearch}/>
  );

 }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Начинать надо с изучения javascript а не с изучения фреймворка.

**Вкратце**, минимальные исправления в ваш код:

```
var Search = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
       return (
           <input type="text" className="search" onChange={this.handleSearch}/>
        );
    },

   handleSearch: function(event) {
      var searchQuery = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
      var displayedContacts = notes.filter(function(el) {
         var searchValue = el.name.toLowerCase();
         return searchValue.indexOf(searchQuery) !== -1;
      });
    }
});
```

**Ошибка unexpected token** - это не ошибка React. Это ошибка, которую выдает транслятор языка, которая в общем случае говорит "Вы мне написали полную чушь с точки зрения языка. Вы скорее всего опечатались или не понимаете что делаете."

**Ожидается:**
Надо вызвать функцию React.createClass; Параметром в нее передать объект {};
Свойствами которого должны быть всякие разные методы, в том числе метод рендер.

```
{
   render: function(){},
   myAwesomeMethod: function(){}
}
```

**Вы делаете:**
Передаете свойством метод рендер:

```
{
    render: function(){
       handleSearch: function(){}
    }
}
```

Внутри метода render объявляете **[метку](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)** handleSearch, после которой идет ключевой слово function. Транслятор дальше ожидает имя функции, не видит его и кидает ошибку. Все логично.

**А еще** правильные парни используют с реактом полный набор es-6 сахара: константы, классы, стрелочные функции, вот это все. Но вам бы основы языка понять сначала.

Comment: Большое спасибо, всё как всегда элементарно. Писал в 2 часа ночи, поэтому и допустил такую ошибку. Изучение идёт в процессе,  большая часть кода была взята с курса, а то что выложил домашнее задание. По Js много читал и изучал, решил начать практику и писать на React соответственно. Методом проб и ошибок, думаю должно получиться. Но как выше и писал, новичок.

Comment: @VadymChecherinda я сам как-то изучал js без учебников, наживую. И потом уже понял что по учебникам было бы гораздо быстрее. Нужно чередовать практику с изучением основ. На одной практике далеко уедешь, как и на одних учебниках.

Comment: Я это учту, спасибо за совет.